# Java SVD as defined by wikipedia

Tags: java, svd

I'm looking for a java library that performs singular value decomposition as descibed in wikipedia: from a matrix A (m X n) get A = U*S*V' where U is m x m, S is m x n and V is n x n.

Anyone can help me ?

Plese don't answer colt or jama because their definition of svd are different from wikipedia's one. In fact colt returns A = U*S*V' where U is m x n, S is n x n and V is n x n.

Alternativley how can I calculate wikipedia's svd using colt ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [JavaDoc for singular decomposition methods](http://jblas.org/javadoc/org/jblas/Singular.html) from [jblas](http://jblas.org/) seems to adhere to the definition as you require it at first sight, but I think you'd have to test to get any certainty.

Another one is [Universal Java Matrix Package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ujmp/), but looking through the JavaDoc is quite bewildering and makes me fear somewhat for its design (interface for defining getters and setters?!)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry its a late reply. But it is better late than never.

If u look closely into the wikipedia page ,

it depicts a 4*5 matrix which is split into a  u:4*4 ,s:4*5,v=5*5

But if u have close look at it , the s matrix has a last row and a last coloumn full of zeros , hence its effectively a 4*4 matrix only . (ie the lower dimension is only used all the time)

I guess this answers your question !